# How to revert Saints Row 4 to an older version against Steam's wishes?

Tags: steam, saints-row-iv

Saints Row 4 released a patch (to include the workshop only) for Windows only recently and broke cross OS multiplayer. We never hit "turn off automatic updates" because we didn't expect over a month of neglect.

[I know Steam doesn't allow reverting explicitly](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266464/can-you-choose-which-version-of-a-game-to-play-on-steam), even though they have the old files available. It also forces updates upon you when launching the game unless in offline mode.

Is there a way to install the older version of Saints Row 4, get it to launch on Steam without updating, and play together?

Comment: Partial duplicate. I guess I can give up on Steam supporting it. Thank you for the link. If there's a Saints Row 4 specific way then this question still stands. I'll edit when I get back to a computer.

Comment: I suspect any answer to this would involve illegitimate methods that we can't really support.

Comment: @Frank Oh shoot. You're right. It's emulation of a game you own that is legal.